# Show only the 5 first options on my multi selects

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, multi-select

I have a multi select and I want when I have to select the options to see only the first 5 options depending on what I write but I don't know how to do

Here is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Creatable from "react-select/lib/Creatable";
import { components } from "react-select";

import "./styles.css";

const options = [
  {
    label: "option 1",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    label: "option 2",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    label: "option 3",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    label: "option 4",
    value: 4
  },
  {
    label: "option 5",
    value: 5
  },
  {
    label: "option 6",
    value: 6
  },
  {
    label: "option 7",
    value: 7
  }
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Creatable
        isMulti
        options={options}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

What I have :

[image: My result]

What I want :

[image: What I want]

How can I do that ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

```
options={options.slice(0,5)}
```

or

```
let newOptions=options.slice(0,5)
...
...
options={newOptions}
```

Comment: It does not work I cannot select option 7 when I type "options 7"

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve this by changing the options with custom search. You can use `onInputChange` method.

Comment: Please show (at least roughly) what that would look like and maybe how to tie it into the provided code.